# Android Studio with vuforia video playback

Tags: android-studio, vuforia, video-player

I am using Vuforia with Android Studio 3.

How to play video in circular format, currently it play in rectangular?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You did not say it specifically but since you are using Vuforia I assume you mean drawing the video in OpenGL ES.

Currently it plays in a rectangular form due to a very simple reason - the MediaPlayer is being drawn to a texture to show the video, and MediaPlayer shows a rectangular.

What you need to do is make the GL texture round - the best approach I believe is changing the texture geometry.
You can find several examples on the web, here is a nice tutorial to guide you through the process:
[Rounded Video corners](https://medium.com/@fabrantes/rounded-video-corners-on-android-3467841cc1b)

[Another example](https://github.com/wasabeef/android-RoundedTextureView)